# why req.body is empty with no error in return

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, api

Im trying to push the the input value to the database, the problem is i get no error in return and the console log of req body in server.js line 24 is empty i can't see anything in the console.
I am sending the input value via the post request on line 18 app.jsx and suppose to see the console log in server.js line 24.
Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong ?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Task from "./Task";
import "./App.scss";

function App() {
  //Value of Input
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);

  const addTodos = async (e) => {
    if (val == "") return;
    e.preventDefault();

    
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/message", { todos })
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    /** */
    setTodos([...todos, val]);
    setVal("");
    /** */
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/message");
      setMessage(res.data);
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((_, key) => key !== id));
  }; //#endregion

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/** On change values*/}
      <form onSubmit={addTodos}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
          value={val}
          type="text"
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, key) => (
          <Task todo={todo} key={key} myKey={key} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      {message.map((e) => (
        <div>{e.todo}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const { Client } = require("pg");
const client = new Client({
  user: "jj",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "dbname",
  password: "rootuser",
  port: 5432,
});
client.connect();
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/message", async (req, res) => {
  const { rows } = await client.query(`SELECT * from todo`);
  res.send(rows);
});

app.post("/message", (req, res) => {
  const { todos } = req.body;
  console.log(todos);
  return res.status(201).json(todos);
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port 5174.`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using  `onSumit` in these line `<form onSubmit={addTodos}></form>`

If you use `onSubmit` then you should bind data by below in react -

```
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append('todos', todos);
```

then send this `bodyFormData` to api -

```
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "myurl",
  data: bodyFormData,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
})
  .then(function (response) {
    //handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (response) {
    //handle error
    console.log(response);
  });
```